# Smali if structure modification

Tags: android, if-statement, smali

i need to modify "if statements" from smali codes to the condition will be true, in java could be something like that:

```
if(a > b){
.....
}
```

convert to:

```
    if(true){
    ...
    }
```

If is it possible to do in smali code? And have anyone idea that how should will modify this structure in smali code?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why do you need to do this?  Just recompile the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the dalvik bytecode, the if statement will be represented as some sort of conditional jump. In this case, likely an `if-le` instruction (short for "if less than or equal to").

The easiest way to accomplish this would be to comment out/remove the `if-le` instruction, so that the instructions it previously would have conditionally jumped over will always be executed instead.

Comment: Thanks for talking some logic. This worked for me, and it's generally a good way to go